# Error #N/A en búsqueda de datos en un documento Excel

Tags: excel

estoy teniendo este error al buscar un nombre en una "base de datos" en mi documento excel, la cosa es que este nombre lo estoy sacando de una lista desplegable que me retorna los nombres de la db que tengo en otra hoja. El error aparece luego de esto:
[image: Proforma]

[image: lista desplegable]

[image: base de datos]

Esta es la fórmula con la que quiero trabajar:
`=BUSCARV([@DESCRIPCION],Items,1,VERDADERO)`
Lo que quiero saber es porqué no me deja recibir la info que quiero de la columna ítem (Obviamente, si selecciono la opción "Descripción" no debería devolver más que un error, pero al seleccionar otras opciones de la lista, me muestra igual el error).

Gracias de antemano <3

Comment: Items o item?? no es lo mismo ;)

Comment: BUSCARV utiliza la primera columna a la izquierda de la selección donde buscas. Tiene toda la pinta que estás buscando en la tabla `Items` cuya primera columna es el campo `Item`, por eso no hay ninguna coincidencia.

Comment: entiendo, y como haría para que me lo lea? hay alguna posibilidad que se pueda buscar?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es traer el ITEM buscando por DESCRIPCIÓN, como ITEM está a la izquierda del campo DESCRIPCIÓN en la tabla donde buscas, no te vale BUSCARV. Prueba con `=INDICE(ITEMS[ITEM];COINCIDIR(B2;ITEMS[DESCRIPCIÓN];0))` donde B2 sería el desplegable del que sacas el dato.

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que tenia que haber hecho, gracias por tu tiempo